# Count and get children's in parent component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a stepper using Angular 7, I don't how to explain in english so code is better to explain ;)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ga-main',
  template: `<app-ga-font>A</app-ga-font><app-ga-font>B</app-ga-font>`,
  styleUrls: ['./ga-main.component.scss']
})
export class GaMainComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ga-font',
  template: `<div class="ga-font-container">
              <div class="ga-font-border">
                <div class="ga-font-box">
                  <ng-content></ng-content>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./ga-font.component.scss']
})
export class GaFontComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**How can I do to get each  elements in GaMain compoent ?**

I need something like this:

```
gaFontObjects = [
  {<div...A...</div>},
  {<div...B...</div>}
]
```

So I can play with them like so:

```
this.gaFontObjects[1].style.display.none;
```

To make a stepper (my use case is insanely different from this exemple but it's same thing globally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this in two parts...

**1. Providing a direct answer with a way to do what you're suggesting**

One way to access the child DOM elements that get rendered by your component would be to:

- inject `ElementRef` into the component's constructor
- use that to get a reference to the component's host element
- call `nativeElement` on the reference to gain access to the DOM node
- call `querySelectorAll` on the DOM node to find all the child nodes. From here you'd have access to the HTMLElement so you *could* manipulate style etc.

Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebxpq7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fga-main.component.ts

If you need access to the child components rather than the DOM nodes, you could also make use of `@ViewChildren`.

**2. Explaining why you (almost certainly) *shouldn't* do this**

Whilst the above is possible, it very much goes against the general Angular approach. In most cases, **you should avoid manipulating the DOM elements directly** unless there is a very particular reason to do so.

In general, you should aim to build a tree of components and communicate between them using `@Input` and `@Output`. You can have control over what gets rendered in each component's template by using `*ngIf` (to selectively show & hide elements based on some condition), `*ngFor` (to loop over elements and dynamically render elements) or bindings such as `[style]` to control CSS properties dynamically.

This allows Angular to handle the lifecycle/rendering/change detection etc. and, generally, makes your application's code more efficient, safer and easier to maintain.

Angular's documentation recommends against direct DOM manipulation, for example see the note of caution here. https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#properties

Here's a much cleaner example based on your scenario (if a little obscure in functionality): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n42xyv?file=src/app/ga-main.component.ts

In this example, the `app-ga-main` component loops over a collection of font names, renders an `app-ga-font` component for each and passes each one a colour via its `fontColor` input. The `app-ga-font` component uses an Angular binding to set the `color` CSS property based on the value provided to the `fontColor` input. You could, for example, choose to show / hide the elements using a binding on `display`, or omit it altogether by using `*ngIf` to determine whether each item should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to play with DOM directly, especially setting display none which Angular doesn't recommend at all?

If you want to get all the children you can do something like below and call the method or set the property of the child component which would handle the UI itself. You can do something like below.

```
@ViewChildren(GaFontComponent) children : QueryList<GaFontComponent>;
```